# Linq nested group by to manipulate identity data

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have been trying to change the shape of one data structure into another for a few days with no luck.

The original data structure is as follows.

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PermissionInRole> PermissionsInRole { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionInRole
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public virtual Feature Feature { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use Linq to change it to this shape.

```
public class ApplicationApiModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FeaturesApiModel> Features { get; set; }
}

public class FeaturesApiModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PermissionsApiModel> Permissions { get; set; } 
}

public class PermissionsApiModel
{
    public string PermissionName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Role> Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have a Collection of Applications, that contains a Collection of Features, that contains a collection of permissions , that contains a collection of roles that have the parent permission.

I am sure that this can be done with linq however I have not managed any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts i ended up with following working code

```
            var query = from role in roles
                    group role by role.PermissionsInRole
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            PinR = g.Key,
                            role = g.ToList()
                        };

        var transferList = (from w in query
            from pr in w.PinR
            select new
            {
                Feature = pr.Feature, Permission = pr.Permission, TransferRole = w.role.Single()
            })
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(o => o.Feature, (key, o) =>
            new FeaturesApiModel
            {
                Name = key.Name,
                Permissions = o.GroupBy(transferObject => transferObject.Permission, (subKey,transferObject) =>
                    new PermissionsApiModel
                    {
                        PermissionName = subKey.Description,
                        Role = transferObject.Select(flatTransferObject => new RoleAPIModel {Name = flatTransferObject.TransferRole.Name})
                    }
                )
            });
```